# select data with links, containing a specific word in the url HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am a new in hive so would appreciate any help. I have a table with links, my task is to choose only data which corresponds to links, containing a specific word (in my case links which contain  "linqtosql") in the url.
I tried:

```
SELECT url, count (*) as visits, min(log_date),  max(log_date) FROM popular_dates WHERE url = '^/.*linqtosql.*' GROUP BY url;
```

output shows 0 results, but it is a mistake.
Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT url, count (*) as visits, min(log_date),  max(log_date) 
FROM popular_dates 
WHERE url like '%linqtosql%' 
GROUP BY url;
```

Or

```
SELECT url, count (*) as visits, min(log_date),  max(log_date) 
FROM popular_dates 
WHERE url rlike 'linqtosql' 
GROUP BY url;
```